# Making a scalar multiplication function in C

Tags: c, vector, scalar

I have written a function definition to get the scalar multiplication for a vector. I was given a prototype to work with but am having confusion with understanding pointers in this. here is the prototype.

```
void scalar_mult(double k, const threeVec_t *src, threeVec_t *dest);
// REQUIRES: src and dest point to threeVec_t objects.
// PROMISES: *dest contains the result of scalar multiplication
//   of k and *src.

struct threeVec {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

typedef struct threeVec threeVec_t;
```

and here is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
void scalar_mult(double k, const threeVec_t *src, threeVec_t *dest)
{
    int i, j, result;
    for (i = 0; i < src; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < dest; j++) {
                        result[i][j] = k * result[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Do you know what a scalar multiplication is? Can you compute a scalar product of two 3-vectors with pencil and paper? Can you do it in C when no pointers are involved? BTW the prototype as posted is wrong, please double check you have copied it correctly.

Comment: what is `i < src` supposed to do? Why do you compare an integer index with an arbitrary pointer? that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should learn the very basics of the language before hammering utter nonsense into a source file and expecting us to teach you C.

Comment: http://abstrusegoose.com/249

Answer (score 0):

You declare `result` as

```
int i, j, result;
```

But your are treating`result` as 2D array which is wrong.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
// it is the callers duty whether the src is null or not
void scalar_mult(double k, const threeVec_t *src, threeVec_t *dest)
{
    dest->x = src->x * k;// arrow operator as member accessed by pointer 
    dest->y = src->y * k;
    dest->z = src->z * k;
}
```

You can call `scalar_mult` from `main` like this:

```
int main() {
    threeVec_t src = {2.0, 3.0, -1.0};
    threeVec_t dest;
    double k = 3.0;

    scalar_mult(k, &src, &dest);

    printf("x = %lf, y = %lf, z = %lf", dest.x, dest.y, dest.z); // Dot operator as member accessed by object 
    return 0;
}
```

[Click here to run live](http://ideone.com/5J2Tck).

Comment: what does dest and src pointing to x do exactly? , so you dont need a for loop in this situation?

Comment: @johnjohn, I guess you need to study a bit about `struct` and _pointer_.

Comment: yessir, but is there a reason you got rid of the for loop?

Comment: Yes, you actually don't need any loop here, because you know the dimension of your vector (dim 3 for you implementation).